# Calculate 2nd order filter with gain

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, filter

I want to make a Sallen & Key 2nd-Order Butterworth highpass filter with a defined gain. Let's say gain is +6 db.

[image]

Then,

R3 = R4 = 1 kOhm

F = 1000 Hz

C = 100 nF

R2 = 2 * Q / ( 2 * 3.14 * F * C )

Now, I would assume that Q = 1 / ( 3 - A), where A = 1 + R3 / R4.
But this table here doesn't agree.

[image]

What am i missing?

Comment: Don’t assume C’s are equal like the LPF

Comment: I don't assume. I command them to be equal.

Comment: Then you cannot get what you asked for

Comment: Since this S&K has gain with positive feedback the  C ratios must change, probably 3:1 for a gain of 2 in the passband. You ought to link your reference.

Comment: @Tony Stewart EE75 Douglas Self "The Design of Active Crossovers. 2nd edition" Chapter 9, p. 247

Comment: The gain of 6 dB at what frequency is that?

Comment: [Highly recommended site](http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/OPseikiHikeisan.htm). It has formulas, calculator, more.

Comment: @a concerned citizen I know this site. Great tools. But I want to understand it, not just use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's your diagram with some annotations:

[image]

(I'm not promising anything about stability here. This is a high pass filter with gain significantly greater than 1. So this is only an idealized analysis, by the numbers. That's all. Not a practical recipe.)

Using [sympy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html):

```
eq1 = Eq( va/(1/s/c) + va/r1 + va/(1/s/c), vo/r1 + vb/(1/s/c) + vi/(1/s/c) )
eq2 = Eq( vb/r2 + vb/(1/s/c), va/(1/s/c) )
eq3 = Eq( vc/r4 + vc/r3, vo/r3 )
eq4 = Eq( vo/r3 + vo/r1, va/r1 + vc/r3 + io )
ans = solve( [eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4, Eq( vb, vc )], [io, va, vb, vc, vo] )
simplify( ans[vo]/vi )

    c**2*r1*r2*s**2*(r3 + r4)/(c**2*r1*r2*r4*s**2 + 2*c*r1*r4*s - c*r2*r3*s + r4)
```

Moving that towards the standard high-pass form leads to the following:

$$\begin{align*}
\omega_{_0}&=\frac1{C\sqrt{R_1\,R_2}}\\\\
\zeta&=\sqrt{\frac{R_1}{R_2}}-\frac12\frac{R_3}{R_4}\sqrt{\frac{R_2}{R_1}}\\\\
K&=1+\frac{R_3}{R_4}\\\\
\mathcal{H}\left(s\right)&=K\frac{s^2}{s^2+2\zeta\,\omega_{_0}s+\omega_{_0}^{\:\!2}}
\end{align*}$$

I'll leave the algebraic details for you to find on your own.

Now, you want to make a Butterworth filter. The 2nd order *normalized* (also known as *analytic*) Butterworth constants are: \$s^2 + \sqrt{2} s + 1\$. (This is where \$\omega_{_0}=1\$.) So it follows that \$2\zeta=\sqrt{2}\$ or \$\zeta=\frac12\sqrt{2}\$. So you have this new requirement:

$$\sqrt{\frac{R_1}{R_2}}-\frac12\frac{R_3}{R_4}\sqrt{\frac{R_2}{R_1}}=\frac12\sqrt{2}$$

From here, it is advisable to set \$R_1=\eta\, R\$ and \$R_2=\frac{R}{\eta}\$ so that \$\omega_{_0}=\frac1{R\,C}\$. This gives you some freedom to adjust these two resistor values. Also, given your desired gain of \$A_v=K=2\$, it follows that \$\frac{R_3}{R_4}=1\$ and that:

$$\begin{align*}
\eta-\frac12\frac1{\eta}&=\frac12\sqrt{2}\\\\
2\eta-\frac1{\eta}&=\sqrt{2}\\\\
\therefore \eta&=\frac14\left(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{10}\right)\approx 1.14412281
\end{align*}$$

From here you can compute \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$, given a desired \$R\$ used in setting \$\omega_{_0}\$.

Let's say \$\omega_{_0}=6283.18531\$ (\$f_{_0}=1\:\text{kHz}\$) and that \$C=100\:\text{nF}\$, per your starting condition. Then it follows that \$R\approx 1.592\:\text{k}\Omega\$ and therefore that \$R_1\approx 1.821\:\text{k}\Omega\$ and \$R_2\approx 1.391\:\text{k}\Omega\$.

My apologies for all that precision, here. But I'm retaining it so you can compare with the results from this [recommended site to compute filter component values](http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/OPseikiHikeisan.htm).

Using the E96 series of resistors, the above site says:

```
R1 = 1.82kΩ
R2 = 1.4kΩ
R3 = 10kΩ
R4 = 10kΩ
C1 = 0.1uF
C2 = 0.1uF
```

Which is obviously quite close to what I just computed.

Also, feel free to go there and look at the plot, as well.

Again. This is a high pass filter with a voltage gain you've specified as \$A_v=2\$! Isolated and by itself, I'm not at all suggesting that you try it with a high performance opamp. But computationally, at least, you can see where the numbers come from. (Or, at least, after you do some algebra.)

P.S. You can also choose to set \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ to the same value. But if so, and if keeping with the Butterworth response, then you will find that the gain is no longer 2. It will have to be less. Something closer to \$3-\sqrt{2}\approx 1.586\$.

Comment: +1 for using open-source software

Comment: @ElliotAlderson That reminds me that I should have linked the site, as well. Done.

Comment: OK - good agreement: The ratio R2/R1 as calculated by you is identical to my calculation (k=R2/R1=0.764).

Comment: @LvW It's a nice demonstration of the power and reach of good theory when different people from likely different cultures, language, and backgrounds can apply it in ways to reach similar results.

Comment: Yes - I fully agree.

Answer (score 1):

> First, I will present a method that uses [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica) to solve this problem. When I was studying this stuff I used the method all the time (without using Mathematica of course).

Well, we are trying to analyze the following [opamp-circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUCuCm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff%27s_current_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\text{I}_2+\text{I}_3\\
\\
\text{I}_1+\text{I}_3+\text{I}_4=\text{I}_2+\text{I}_5
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_4}\\
\\
\text{I}_5=\frac{\text{V}_3-\text{V}_4}{\text{R}_5}\\
\\
\text{I}_5=\frac{\text{V}_4}{\text{R}_6}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Substitute \$(2)\$ into \$(1)\$, in order to get:

$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_2}+\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}+\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_3}+\text{I}_4=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_2}+\text{I}_5\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_4}+\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}+\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_3}+\text{I}_4=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_4}+\text{I}_5\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}+\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_3}+\text{I}_4=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_2}+\frac{\text{V}_3-\text{V}_4}{\text{R}_5}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}+\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_3}+\text{I}_4=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_4}+\frac{\text{V}_4}{\text{R}_6}
\end{cases}\tag3
$$

Now, using an [ideal opamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier#Ideal_op_amps), we know that:

$$\text{V}_x:=\text{V}_+=\text{V}_-=\text{V}_2=\text{V}_4\tag4$$

So we can rewrite equation \$(3)\$ as follows:

$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_x}{\text{R}_2}+\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}+\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_3}+\text{I}_4=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_x}{\text{R}_2}+\text{I}_5\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}=\frac{\text{V}_x}{\text{R}_4}+\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}+\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_3}+\text{I}_4=\frac{\text{V}_x}{\text{R}_4}+\text{I}_5\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}+\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_3}+\text{I}_4=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_x}{\text{R}_2}+\frac{\text{V}_3-\text{V}_x}{\text{R}_5}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}+\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_3}+\text{I}_4=\frac{\text{V}_x}{\text{R}_4}+\frac{\text{V}_x}{\text{R}_6}
\end{cases}\tag5
$$

Now, we can solve for the transfer function:

$$\mathcal{H}:=\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{V}_\text{i}}=\frac{\text{R}_3\text{R}_4\left(\text{R}_5+\text{R}_6\right)}{\text{R}_6\left(\text{R}_1\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)+\text{R}_3\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_4\right)\right)-\text{R}_1\text{R}_4\text{R}_5}\tag6$$

Where I used the following Mathematica-code:

```
In[1]:=Clear["Global`*"];
V2 = Vx;
V4 = Vx;
FullSimplify[
 Solve[{I1 == I2 + I3, I1 + I3 + I4 == I2 + I5, I1 == (Vi - V1)/R1, 
   I2 == (V1 - V2)/R2, I3 == (V1 - V3)/R3, I2 == V2/R4, 
   I5 == (V3 - V4)/R5, I5 == V4/R6}, {I1, I2, I3, I4, I5, V1, V3, 
   Vx}]]

Out[1]={{I1 -> ((R4 R5 - (R2 + R3) R6) Vi)/(
   R1 R4 R5 - (R1 (R2 + R3) + R3 (R2 + R4)) R6), 
  I2 -> (R3 R6 Vi)/(-R1 R4 R5 + R1 (R2 + R3) R6 + R3 (R2 + R4) R6), 
  I3 -> ((R4 R5 - R2 R6) Vi)/(
   R1 R4 R5 - (R1 (R2 + R3) + R3 (R2 + R4)) R6), 
  I4 -> ((R3 R4 + 2 R4 R5 - 2 R2 R6) Vi)/(-R1 R4 R5 + 
    R1 (R2 + R3) R6 + R3 (R2 + R4) R6), 
  I5 -> (R3 R4 Vi)/(-R1 R4 R5 + R1 (R2 + R3) R6 + R3 (R2 + R4) R6), 
  V1 -> (R3 (R2 + R4) R6 Vi)/(-R1 R4 R5 + R1 (R2 + R3) R6 + 
    R3 (R2 + R4) R6), 
  V3 -> (R3 R4 (R5 + R6) Vi)/(-R1 R4 R5 + R1 (R2 + R3) R6 + 
    R3 (R2 + R4) R6), 
  Vx -> (R3 R4 R6 Vi)/(-R1 R4 R5 + R1 (R2 + R3) R6 + 
    R3 (R2 + R4) R6)}}
```

My equation was also confirmed using [LTspice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LTspice).

---

When we want to apply the derivation from above to your circuit we need to use [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform) (I will use lower case function names for the functions that are in the (complex) s-domain, so \$\text{y}\left(\text{s}\right)\$ is the Laplace transform of the function \$\text{Y}\left(t\right)\$):

- $$\text{R}_1=\frac{1}{\text{sC}_1}\tag7$$
- $$\text{R}_2=\frac{1}{\text{sC}_2}\tag8$$

So, we can rewrite the transfer function as:

$$\mathscr{H}\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{\text{R}_3\text{R}_4\left(\text{R}_5+\text{R}_6\right)}{\text{R}_6\left(\frac{1}{\text{sC}_1}\left(\frac{1}{\text{sC}_2}+\text{R}_3\right)+\text{R}_3\left(\frac{1}{\text{sC}_2}+\text{R}_4\right)\right)-\frac{1}{\text{sC}_1}\text{R}_4\text{R}_5}\tag9$$

Now, when working with sinusoidal signals we can use \$\text{s}:=\text{j}\omega\$ (where \$\text{j}^2=-1\$ and \$\omega=2\pi\text{f}\$ with \$\text{f}\$ is the frequency of the input signal in Hertz). Now, we know the values for \$\text{C}_1=\text{C}_2=100\cdot10^{-9}\space\text{F}\$ and \$\text{R}_5=\text{R}_6=1000\space\Omega\$ and we know that at \$\omega=2\pi\cdot1000\space\text{rad/sec}\$ we have \$20\log_{10}\left(\left|\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|\right)=6\$. So by setting \$\text{R}_3=\text{R}_4:=\text{R}\$ we can solve for it and get:

$$\text{R}\approx1587.8\space\Omega\tag{10}$$

Where I used the following code:

```
In[2]:=Clear["Global`*"];
R1 = 1/(s*C1);
R2 = 1/(s*C2);
s = I*\[Omega];
\[Omega] = 2*Pi*1000;
C1 = c;
C2 = c;
c = 100*10^(-9);
R5 = 1000;
R6 = 1000;
R3 = R;
R4 = R;
x = FullSimplify[
   Sqrt[ComplexExpand[
       Re[(R3 R4 (R5 + R6))/(-R1 R4 R5 + R1 (R2 + R3) R6 + 
         R3 (R2 + R4) R6)]]^2 + 
     ComplexExpand[
       Im[(R3 R4 (R5 + R6))/(-R1 R4 R5 + R1 (R2 + R3) R6 + 
         R3 (R2 + R4) R6)]]^2], Assumptions -> R > 0];
FullSimplify[Solve[{20 Log10[x] == 6, R > 0}, R]]

Out[2]={{R -> (1/\[Pi])
   2500 \[Sqrt](2/
       3 (-125 - 80 10^(1/5) - 50 10^(2/5) - 32 10^(3/5) - 
         20 10^(4/5) + Sqrt[
         81125 + 51200 10^(1/5) + 32300 10^(2/5) + 20384 10^(3/5) + 
          12860 10^(4/5)]))}}

In[3]:=N[%2]

Out[3]={{R -> 1587.8}}
```

Comment: I need to get Q = 0.707. Can't get that with R3 = R4 and Gain = 2.

Comment: @Viktor and what are the cutoff frequencies or what is the resonant frequency and what should the gain be at the resonant and/or the cutoff frequencies?

Comment: Let's say cutoff frequency is 3 kHz. Don't care about resonant frequency. Gain is +6 db above fc

Comment: @Viktor The S&K design you show cannot have the Q set independent from the voltage gain. One is *determined* by the other.

Comment: @jonk Doesn't it also depend on the R3/R4 ratio. Go here http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/OPseikiLowkeisan.htm and change only R2 value. The gain stays the same, but the Q varies.

Comment: @Viktor I forgot to add that what I wrote is true when the capacitor values are the *same*. I should have written more precisely. My mistake. But I was drawn to that mistake by your diagram, which shows both capacitors as **C**.

Comment: @jonk They are the same actually. I don't think that should matter.

Comment: @Viktor Have you worked out the nodal equations? If you are right, then it should be obvious from that result.

Comment: @Viktor In your diagram, \$\zeta=\sqrt{\frac{R_1}{R_2}}-\frac12\frac{R_3}{R_4}\sqrt{\frac{R_2}{R_1}}\$. If you want \$A_v=2\$ then it follows that \$R_3=R_4\$, correct? Also, I think you specified already also that \$R_1=R_2\$. So this means that \$\zeta=\frac12\$ and \$Q=\frac1{2\,\zeta}=1\$. However, for a Butterworth filter you require \$\zeta=\frac12\sqrt{2}\approx 0.7071\$. So it's not a Butterworth filter, anymore. If you want to keep the Butterworth, then you will need to change something. That's only my opinion, though. Others are free to differ.

Comment: @jonk R1 isn't equal R2. I am looking for a formula to calculate them for fixed gain and C1=C2.

Comment: @Viktor state clearly what you want, because using that I can write Mathematica code that finds the values for you. State ALL the requirements for your circuit!

Comment: @Jan Design filter with Q=0.707 Fs = 3 kHz, gain +6 dB. C1=C2=47nF.

Comment: @Viktor and is the 6 dB gain at Fs? And what is Fs?

Comment: @Jan Usually, that's the transfer function \$K\$ at \$\omega=\infty\$ for a high pass like this. Added note: The significant gain and the fact that this is a high pass probably means other problems, though, in a non-ideal world.

Comment: @Jan If you'd put all that stuff into standard form, I might recognize it. Please consider the idea of shooting for \$\mathcal{H}\!\left(s\right)=K\frac{s^{2}}{s^2+2\zeta\,\omega_{_0}s+\omega_{_0}^{\:\!2}}\$? I believe doing this would also help the OP, because of something else: namely, setting \$R_1=\eta\, R\$ and \$R_2=\frac{R}{\eta}\$ so that \$\sqrt{R_1\,R_2}=R\$ and gaining some freedom in adjusting \$\zeta\$ per filter needs while keeping the gain.

Answer (score 1):

**Transfer function** for two **equal capacitors C** and gain **A=2**:

H(s)=N(s)/D(s) with

**N(s)=(s² * 2 * R1 * R2  C²)** and **D(s)=[1+s(R1 * 2C - R2 * C) + s² * R1 * R2 * C²]**

From this (comparison with the general transfer function) with **k=R2/R1**

Pole frequency **wp=1/[R1 * C * SQRT(k)]** and

Pole-Q **Qp=SQRT(k)/(2-k)**=0.7071 with

k1,2=2 + [1 (-+)SQRT(1+4)]

**k1**=2 + 1 - 2.236 =**0.764** (for k2 Qp is negative).

**R2=0.764 * R1**

---

**EDIT** (completion):

Here is the general transfer function for a Sallen-Key filter (lowpass, highpass) with gain **A=1+(R3/R4)** and the horizontal elements Y0 and Y5:

H(s)=N(s)/D(s) with

**N(s)=A * Y0 * Y5** and

**D(s)=Y2(Y0+Y1+Y5) + Y5[Y0 * Y1 * (1-A)]**

Fot a **highpass** we select:  **Y0=sC0, Y5=sC5, Y1=1/R1 and Y2=1/R2**

For **C0=C5** and **A=2** the highpass function results as given above (after some mathematical manipulatons.)

Comment: Where do you account for gain in your equations?

Comment: @Viktor, the gain A=2 is included in the quations. At first. the factor "2" in the numerator N(s) and, secondly, in the denominator D(s) it is the "-" sign which results from C*R2(1-A). If you want I can give you the general form for a Sallen-Key filter with different C and the gain A.

Comment: Viktor, see my edit.

Comment: In the formula for Pole-Q does the denominatior (2-k) stand for (A-k) ?

Comment: The expression for Qp is Qp=SQRT(kck)/[1+kc+kck(1-A)] with kc=C5/C0=1 (equal capacitors) and A=2 we have Qp=SQRT(k)/(2-k)

Comment: Than my math doesn't add up for some reason. For Q = 0.707: sqrt(k)/(A-k)=0.707 -> k^2-(A+2)k+A^2=0. Solve this, we get k1,2=((A+2)+sqrt(-3A^2+2A+4))/2, which doesn't have a soultion for A > 1.53.

Comment: Error: Must be k^2-(A+1)2k+A^2=0

Comment: My bad. Thank you.

Comment: Now coming back to that table, this formula works for A = 2. But not for any other values from that table. Why is that?

Comment: The gain has a direct influence on the pole-Q (see the mid term in the denominator). Hence, component values are different for Butterworth, Chebyshev, Bessel, etc.

Comment: I am not talking about component ratio's, that we just calculated using your formulas. They don't correspond with the ratio's from that table.

Comment: For a gain of "2" I read from your table: R2/R1=0.764. What is your concern?

Comment: Any other gain from the table.

Comment: Yes - when you change the gain, the filter response changes also (Quality factor). However, when we do NOT want such a change (remain Butterworth response) the parts values must change (compensate the Q change)

Comment: Another simple design is with two equal C and two equal R values. However, in this case, the required gain is A=3-1/Qp.  This gives A=1.5858 for Qp=0.7071 - hard to achieve

Comment: Yes the parts' values must change. That's where we started - how to calculate them was the original question.

Comment: ...and I think, I have shown how to calculate the values (depending on the pole data, Qp and wp, for the desired response) . For 2nd-order Butterworth, the pole frequency wp is identical to the 3dB cut-off frequency.

Answer (score 0):

From "A handbook of Active Filters", by D.E. Johnson, et al., reference VCVS high-pass filter. This uses tables of coefficients for the various types of filters (butterworth, cheby, elliptic, ...). Warning, C is a coefficient, C1 are the capacitor values.

For 2nd order butterworth coefficients:

```
B = sqrt(2)
C = 1.0
```

Equations:

```
R2 = 4 * C / {[B + sqrt(B^2 + 8 * C * (K + 1)] * w * C1}
R1 = C / {w^2 * C1^2 * R2}
R4 = K * R2 / {K - 1}
R3 = K * R2
```

where:

```
K = gain
w = 2*π*f
C1 = capacitors (arbitrary value, same value for both)
```

R4 & R3 equations are given to optimize DC offset. You can make them any reasonable value if you don't care about DC offset.

Choosing C1 = 100nF:

```
R2 = 1391.77 -> nearest 1% value = 1.40k
R1 = 1821.85 -> nearest 1% value = 1.82k
R3 = R4 = 2783.54 -> nearest 1% value = 2.87k
```

Spice simulation shows this to be very close to what you want. Watch out for your choice of dielectric for C1. Either use plastic or COG dielectrics. If using COG (NPO) dielectric, you may want to make C1 = 10nF. X7R, and other class 2 ceramic dielectrics, will introduce distortion, have a strong temperature dependence, and change value over time.

Comment: The OP wrote in a comment responding to someone's suggestion to use already existing applets to compute values: *"I know this site. Great tools. But I want to understand it, not just use it."* Can you expand a little in order to help address the OP's concerns?