# I need to design a second-order high-pass filter, gain 2 and cut frequency of 500 Hz. Using chebyshev response of 0.1 dB

Tags: operational-amplifier, high-pass-filter

I took the parameters from the MT-206 table of Analog Devices. I did not find in any book the chebyshev response of 0.1dB. https://www.analog.com/media/en/training-seminars/tutorials/MT-206.pdf
[image]

[image]

I performed the following steps to find the value of the elements
[image]

First: I'm pretty sure this is wrong.

Second: I have to take into account the Q of chebyshev's answer or I can only take into account the gain I want out of 2.

Third: The gain over there is almost around 5. Is there a way to "decrease the gain"?

Comment: First: You are correct. The gain formula is wrong, it should be 1 +R3/R4 which affects Q’s from positive feedback. A Chebychev ripple of 0dB becomes a Butterworth filter,

Comment: I don't quite recognize that topology, which one is it? Sallen-Key? Multiple feedback? ...?

Comment: S&K... your component tolerances might exceed 0.1 dB ripple.  Use TI Filter Design and choose tolerance of parts

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 That doesn't look like any [Sallen-Key](http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/Fkeisan.htm) I know of. Or multiple feedback. Or any other.

Comment: It's Sallen-Key

Comment: S&K only uses positive feedback. but with gain, uses the R Ratio for negative feedback

Comment: A Chebychev ripple of 0dB becomes a Butterworth filter, but at 1/2 the cutoff frequency or 250Hz at -3dB below the passband gain

Comment: @Dragnovith That is a malformed S&K, look in the link I gave you. Compare the way the RC network is in your picture vs the ones listed there. The site is very reliable. Still, I have to ask: are you restricted to a certain topology, in particular, or are you allowed to use whichever one you want, as long as the response is that of a 0.1 dB Chebyshev?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen It is not malformed. It is the only way to increase gain above 1 in S&K/ Those are only unity gain versions

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen You can use any topology as long as it respects the 0.1 dB chebyshev response and the other parameters mentioned. This topology was passed on in class why I am using it. I took a look at your website.

Comment: @Dragnovith Then you saw the formulas and the available topologies. There are your answers. I still say it's malformed because the S&K has only 2xR+2xC. With R3/R4 it allows different gain. What you're using is 3xR+2xC. You already have LTspice. Assign `{34k/a}` and `{34k/(1-a)}` to the two resistors and then use `.step param a 0.1 0.9 0.1` to see the effect it has on the overall response. Then remove the `(1-a)` resistor and set the `1/a` resistor to `34k`, and compare with a `Laplace=2*3.31404/((s/w)^2+(s/w)*2.37236+3.31404)` (with `w=2*pi*500/1.93`, needs freq. scaling).

Comment: @a concerned citizen, the general S&K topology has 5 passive elements (like the S&K bandpass). For lowpass and highpass responses, the 5th element is "redundant" - that means: It is not necessary to realize the desired functions. But, of course. it is not forbidden. The principle of all S&K topologies is the fixed-gain stage (in comparison to the multi-fedback structure)

Comment: Was that a 0.1dB cutoff or a -3dB cutoff , catch my drift? It’s ambiguous. If you said BW then it’s -3dB to me

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen why do you insist on S&K active filter with gain malformed when the OKAWA link you gave showed that as valid, similar to Filter Pro adopted by that I used?

Comment: @LvW I'm looking through Dimopoulos and the only time when there are 5 elements (except the gain network) is the bandpass (and bandstop). The generic S&K I see has only 4 elements. And for bandpass, the reactive elemens are series-shunt, which means that even frequency transformations will preserve a series-shunt topology, so it can only be bandpass<->bandstop. At least, that's what I see in the the book I have. I wouldn't mind seeing that generic S&K. If what I said is misleading, that's certainly not my purpose. I'd like to correct myself.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Look closer, the `Ra` in OP's LTspice schematic is non-existent in both Okawa and Filter pro. That's what I was referring to, but as LvW points out, I might be wrong, so I'll stand corrected. But what you're referring to is identical to what I have in mind, therefore it is in agreement with what I said.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen. TY you’re right I missed that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not what your Prof expects but it is how I would approach it. I assume he wants you to compute it. This way takes a few minutes.

**500 Hz HPF 2nd order Chebychev response S&K filter Av=2 in passband = 6.02 dB  +/- 0.1dB**

[image]

Your link shows the analytic approach only for a unity gain 0.1 dB normalized frequency response on [page 9](https://www.analog.com/media/en/training-seminars/tutorials/MT-206.pdf#9)

Table 1.2 on p.2 shows the Ripple BW f to -3dB f for 0.1 dB ripple filter and only the  2nd order has the value **1.93432**= f_ripple/f-3dB which supports my comment that for this filter when Ripple = 0 equals the Butterworth Filter at 1/2 the cutoff frequency.

**This is important not to confuse the two bandwidth definitions** as some may assume BW is always -3dB rather than the "Ripple BW" where the ratio varies depending on the order of the filter.  In the other filter designs, you can choose the attenuation level where the phase has maximum linearity like -6 dB or -10 dB. but in higher order filters, usually you defined the Stop-Band attenuation and frequency with the Pass-Band gain or attenuation with frequency.

- Here I used Falstad's Analog filter site and chose the -3dB BW =   500 Hz /1.93432 = 259 Hz  and they only offer unity gain filter tools. Again you may scale up impedance to the RC values with the same product just for low current on CMOS type Op Amps.

[image]

The table of parameters for unity gain from your Analog Devices link and for *giggles and kicks* a Quad Op Amp's worth of an 8th order filter.

[image]

Comment: Okay, I'll take a closer look, thanks !!

Comment: Okay any comments?

Answer (score 5):

Here's your diagram with some annotations:

[image]

Although I've never seen this particular arrangement before, I'll argue that the above can be reduced to:

[image]

Where \$R_2=\frac{R_a\,R_b}{R_a+R_b}\$ and \$A=\frac{1}{1+\frac{R_b}{R_a}}\$.

Since \$A\$ is in series with \$R_2\$, we can swap positions when performing the nodal analysis as seen below:

Using [sympy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) and assuming \$C=C_1=C_2\$:

```
eq1 = Eq( va/ra + va/rb + va/(1/s/c) + va/(1/s/c), vp/(1/s/c) + vi/(1/s/c) + (A*vo)/r2 + 0/ra)
eq2 = Eq( vp/(1/s/c) + vp/r1, va/(1/s/c) + 0/r1 )
eq3 = Eq( vm/r3 + vm/r4, vo/r3 + 0/r4 )
eq4 = Eq( vo/r2 + vo/r3, vm/r3 + (va/A)/r2 + io )
eq5 = Eq( vp, vm )
ans = solve( [eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4, eq5], [io, va, vp, vm, vo] )
tf = simplify( ans[vo]/vi )
n0 = factor( -expand(fraction(simplify(ans[vo]/vi))[0]), s )
d0 = factor( -expand(fraction(simplify(ans[vo]/vi))[1]), s )
np = Poly( n0, s )
dp = Poly( d0, s )
w0 = sqrt( simplify(dp.coeffs()[2] / dp.coeffs()[0]) )
alpha = simplify( 1/2 * dp.coeffs()[1] / dp.coeffs()[0] )
zeta = simplify( alpha / w0 )
K = expand( simplify( np.coeffs()[0] / dp.coeffs()[0] ) )
```

So now I find:

$$\begin{align*}
R_2&= R_a\mid\mid R_b = \frac{R_a\,R_b}{R_a+R_b}
\\\\
A&=\frac1{1+\frac{R_b}{R_a}}
\\\\
K&=1+\frac{R_3}{R_4}
\\\\
\omega_{_0}&=\frac1{C\sqrt{R_1\,R_2}}
\\\\
\zeta&=\sqrt{\frac{R_2}{R_1}}-\frac12\sqrt{\frac{R_1}{R_2}}\bigg[A\,K-1\bigg]
\\\\
\mathcal{H}\left(s\right)&=K\frac{s^2}{s^2+2\zeta\,\omega_{_0}s+\omega_{_0}^{\:\!2}}
\end{align*}$$

The Chebyshev function you are looking to achieve (if I understand it) is:

```
eta0 = solve( Eq( 10**(-0.1/10), 1/(1+x**2) ), x )[1]
alp0 = arcsinh( 1 / eta1 ) / 2
chr0 = Poly( simplify((s-(-sinh(alp1)*sin(pi/4)+i*cosh(alp1)*cos(pi/4)))*(s-(-sinh(alp1)*sin(3*pi/4)+i*cosh(alp1)*cos(3*pi/4)))).n(), s )
w0chr = sqrt( chr0.coeffs()[2] / chr0.coeffs()[0] )
d0chr = chr0.coeffs()[1] / sqrt( chr0.coeffs()[0] * chr0.coeffs()[2] )
d0chr, w0chr

    (1.30317045127507, 1.82044969090790)
```

Let's look at a table from R. P. Sallen and E. L. Key's *"TR-50: A Practical Method of Designing RC Active Filters,"* 6 May 1954:

[image]

Similar values there.

As the frequency shape only depends on the value of \$d=2\,\zeta\$, we can set \$\zeta\approx 0.6516\$ for this case and then solve the above equations for the filter.

(Do keep in mind that I believe the \$0.1\:\text{dB}\$ down point will be \$\approx 1.82\times\$ your designed \$\omega_{_0}\$, based upon the above calculations I just performed. This could mean it's located at about \$f_c\approx 910 \:\text{Hz}\$. So this may not be expected or desired. If not, you'll have to take this factor into account, setting \$f_c= 500 \:\text{Hz}\$ and computing a now-reduced \$\omega_{_0}\$, before designing the filter. But I don't know what's expected. So I'm leaving it here.)

I think that spells out enough to get going. And I believe it is enough to say that your odd arrangement with \$R_a\$ and \$R_b\$ (which I've not seen) can be used. I'm not sufficiently familiar with it, yet, to know if there's a great purpose in arranging it with the extra resistor. Perhaps that will settle in, later. But at least I think it can be used to get where you need to go.

Comment: Jonk - interesting modification (second diagram in your answer). Here is another modification with simplified design equations (4-element version): Use of an additional buffer after the first node (decoupling of both RC sections). This modification allows that both gain stages have unity gain with reduced component spread (if compared with the single gain stage version).

Comment: @LvW That had crossed my mind. I only avoided it to focus on the main thrust I wanted to convey to aconcernedcitizen. But it's a really good idea. I may add a section later. It's actually worth the trouble. (But I have other things to do in the meantime, though, and I'd also like to see what aconcernedcitizen thinks, as well. He may find something I need to adjust. I think I got it right... and I do make mistakes. ;)

Comment: @LvW Ah. I found my earlier comment made before I wrote that answer: *"To me, that active opamp in the OP's question here has its output fed to two, not one, voltage dividers. One that goes to an opamp input and the other that feeds back."* So yes, it had crossed my mind.

Comment: @jonk Yes, that's what I tried, and it reduces to the S&K version. As I replied to LvW, this is just the generic SAB derived from the bridged T network, with the shunt R split. This is the start of S&K, but not S&K. But, yes, this is what I have seen, too.

Comment: To complete the picture: Less known - but there are also negative-gain S&K structures. However, due to relatively large gain values (if compared with pos.-gain SK) these filters have larger active sensitivities (influence of real opamp gains) and the application is restricted to small quality figures.

Answer (score 4):

**Dragnovith**, may I give you some general information?

1.) You can use the shown S&K topology with 5 passive components - however, it is not necessary to have the first grounded resistor. The design with only 4 elements is somewhat simpler.

2.) For Chebyshev responses it is quite common to use not the -3dB criterion to define  the begin of the passband (cut-off). Instead, the first crossing of the maximum gain line (in your case "2") is used. That means, it is the ripple which defines the passband.
This is important to know when you are trying to use tabulated values for the pole data (or for the parts values). Therefore, check which kind of definitions is used for the data.

3.) Normally, the tabulated figures are normalized to the corresponding pole frequency wp. This is important to know because there is a difference between pole frequency and cut-off frequency wc. So - before using these values you must do "denormalization".

4.) For each 2nd-order filter structure - and for each basic filter function - there are formulas which relate the pole data (pole frequency wp and pole quality Qp) to the various passive parts values.

5.) **Example**: Highpass, 2nd order, Chebyshev with 0.1dB ripple:
**wc/wp=1.82 and Qp=0.767.**

Comment: Darn. Although I'd write more, you've hit on the key points and now I don't want to write. +1! (My first experience with Tschebyscheff was with approximation theory using nodes/nonlinear minimax/Clenshaw–Curtis quadrature -- 1973/74 for me as I was faced with writing transcendental function libraries. So it was a pleasure to revisit it towards the end of the 1970's when I first designed and built a 600 bps FSK modem with async detector and needed to 1st learn about filters generally, as I was then totally ignorant, and then design a practical 6-pole transmit and 10-pole receive filter.)

Comment: I should add that R. P. Sallen and E. L Key's ***"TR-50: A Practical Method of Designing RC Active Filters,"*** 6 May 1954 (before their official public paper in 1955, which was a complete white-wash of their earlier report -- secret at the time, unfortunately) covers Tschebyscheff filters well (and uses that spelling.)

Comment: TR-50 covers at least (I'd need to recheck to be sure) 25 different filter topologies, including quite a few multi-active-amplifier ones (described as "2 active inputs".) Just FYI. This includes formulas needed to develop each of them. They focus more on Butterworth and Tschebyscheff, with regard to specific tables, though.

Comment: @jonk I managed to find that paper and, looking through all those 25 schematics, I can't see anywhere 5 elements for lowpass/highpass. I'm not talking about the series or parallel RC elements. The only topologies I know where 5 elements are used are the bandpass/bandstop. Is there anywhere I can read about a 5 element S&K lowpass/highpass? I am very curious at this point. It seems everyone knows about it, but me.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen No. That particular one isn't there. But the modification is just a voltage divider, isn't it? You can transform it (Thevenin) into a change in the +K for the opamp and a single resistor value, yes? To me, that active opamp in the OP's question here has its output fed to *two*, not one, voltage dividers. One that goes to an opamp input and the other that feeds back. I've not sat down to analyze it, per se, but it seems to me that the resulting equation would fit one of the patterns discussed.

Comment: Note: Just to make clear LvW's point (2) above, see [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFRyS.png). I annotated a picture I found at [Analog Devices: DSP Guide: Chapter 20](http://www.matheonics.com/Tutorials/Chebyshev.html). Do note that this is ***not*** (necessarily) the -3 dB point.

Comment: It seems that varying the ratio according to that \$\alpha\$ parameter it affects the Q, without affecting the gain. But it does so by lowering it, which means that the base R is calculated for a max Q. Which means not using them is a better alternative since the transfer function is, usually, calculated from the begining, with a fixed Q. The gain network might affect it a bit, but so will the rest of the component's tolerances. So I have real doubts now that the 5 element version is better than the 4 one. Somewhat to be expected, since that's the only one I can find in the literature.

Comment: Correction to the above: it seems \$\alpha>1\$ is possible (up to a point), which makes Q independent from the gain. *Now* the 5 element is better.

Comment: @jonk It turns out the transfer function ends up with negative R if it's greater than one, so it's back to square one. I still say 4 elements is the way to go, but I am still curious to read about the 5 element version (that is not a bandpass/bandstop).

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Well, you've probably already done the perfunctory transfer function for the OP's layout. I'll cobble up my own when I get a moment, later today, so that I can see what you are seeing. Even I don't trust my own intuition. In fact, I trust it less than I do that of others. So it's worth doing, I guess. Actually, I think this might be a good time for me to practice those FACTs that Basso keeps reminding me about (with cudos to Dr. Middlebrook, now deceased some few years.)

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Well, you prompted me to actually write down what I was thinking about. See if the argument makes sense.

Comment: Quote (concerned citizen): "Is there anywhere I can read about a 5 element S&K lowpass/highpass?" I remenber that the 5-element version is treated in a filter book by Martin&Sedra. (But I am not sure - my memory is not as good as it was some years before).

Comment: .....no, its from Sedra and Brackett.

Comment: Finally, the mystery solved! That's just a generic single amplifier biquad, derived from the bridged T network, where the shunt R is split into `R/a` and `R/(1-a)`, one of them going in the input. S&K derived their circuit based on this one, noting that the `R/(1-a)` and `R/a` can be combined -- just like in @jonk's answer -- to form one single `R` (since `a` would only lower the Q). That's how the S&K topology was born. I felt like going nuts over this. :-)

Comment: Mmmhh... I think the bridged T-network (can produce complex zeros) is the generic circuit for deriving the MFB (multi-feedback structure). In contrast, the generic network for all S&K filters is a simple 4-element ladder structure (for input coupling and feedback), which cannot produce complex zeros (hence only allpole filters are possible). To feed the input signal into the network we must use the first grounded element - however, in order to allow flexibility this element is realized by two parts in parallel, and only ONE is connected to the input. So we arrive at a 5-element basic circuit.

Answer (score 2):

If you can choose the topology then use the proper Sallen-Key that you see in the [link I gave](http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/OPseikiHikeisan.htm). That only uses 2xR+2xC (plus 2xR, the gain network). The link on ADI you gave is part of a book called [*Op Amp Applications (Walter G. Jung)*](https://www.analog.com/en/education/education-library/op-amp-applications-handbook.html), and it's freely available. In there you'll find the Sallen-Key highpass (fig. 5-68) and ready-to-use formulas.

However, tables are really not my thing and, when I tried to use them, the values I got for `R1` and `R2` didn't seem to fit the response, so I calculated them based on the transfer function:

$$\left\{\begin{aligned}
\omega^2&=\dfrac{1}{R_1R_2C^2} \\
Q^2&=\dfrac{1}{R_1R_2C^2}\cdot\dfrac{1}{\left(\dfrac{2}{R_2C}+\dfrac{1-K}{R_1C}\right)^2}
\end{aligned}\right.$$

with 4 solutions, out of which two are negative and the 3rd giving the correct magnitude but the wrong phase (poles end up in the right-hand plane, unstable). Which leaves the two, correct values, given by:

$$\left\{\begin{aligned}
R_1&=\dfrac{\sqrt{8Q^2+1}+1}{4\omega QC}&=3.52\;\mathrm{k}\Omega \\
R_2&=\dfrac{\sqrt{8Q^2+1}-1}{2\omega QC}&=2.88\;\mathrm{k}\Omega
\end{aligned}\right.$$

[image: test]

The gain is 2, the ripple ~0.1 dB, the corner frequency is at -3 dB, 500 Hz (usually considered the end of the passband for a Chebyshev). I would have chosen a multiple feedback, it saves one resistor and handles Q better, but at 0.1 dB, it's fine as it is.

Comment: The high pass ripple BW of 0.1dB is not 500 Hz. what is it?  That’s the book I used in the 70’s

Comment: Interestingly, I didn't know this book or that method. Thanks, I'll take a look

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 There is a comma between the `-3 dB` and the `500 Hz` which changes the meaning of the phrase to a list: 1) the gain is two, 2) the ripple is 0.1 dB, and 3) the attenuation at the corner frequency is `-3 dB @ 500 Hz`. I did not say anywhere that the ripple is in Hz.

Comment: yet interestly, the Filter Pro app.  assumes 0.1dB ripple is the passband of 500 Hz and the -3dB freq. is listed as  “Cutoff Freq. 274.657 Hz,  which is why I indicated to clarify this distinction and not assume, as there are 2 BW definitions. But then I always doubt answers with excess sigfigs ;) yet appreciate the choice of component tolerances.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 That's strange, but I'm a little bit worried on this part: "*Center Frequency Attenuation: 6 dB*". I wonder why they chose that. Maybe they inadvertently considred the gain? That would be a blunder, but not the first in the history of software. At any rate, it would explain why they say 274 Hz (they consider the -6 dB point).

Comment: Tony Steward, the ratio 500/274.657=1.82 can be found in the filter tables. It is the normalized frequency wc/wp (cutoff-to-pole frequency ratio). Therefore, it is important to check which passband edge is used for the tabulated figures. (see the last line in my detailed answer)

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I think you misread. It doesn’t say that . It says what I wrote; Gain = 2, Passband = 500 Hz to the last -ve ripple , which jonk’s comment above  agrees with and LvW agrees with me above showing Cutoff as the higher frequency of a HPF defined by ripple frequency BW or inversely -3dB half power point  to Ripple BW ratio, so again never assume cuttoff without the reference which variables define BW. we could vote on it but the critical factor was 0.1dB so that’s what I would assume as cutoff until verified.

Comment: Now that 0.1dB has been thrashed , and achievable with 1% parts it would be a shame to be off by assumption by 182% ;)

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 You're right, I was mislead by the info beneath the schematic.

Comment: It shouldn’t say “Center” for a HPF

Answer (score 1):

[I proposed an answer to a similar problem.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/562193/calculate-2nd-order-filter-with-gain/562263#562263)

This uses a table solution. For your 0.1dB Cheby filter the coefficients are:

```
B = 2.372356
C = 3.314037
```

The corner frequency is where the ripple crosses the 0dB (in your case, the 6dB) point as opposed to the -3dB point.

Answer (score 0):

How many comments, I'm reading and learning. But I would really like to thank those who helped, thank you very much!